# Find all string “ID” in a .txt file

Tags: java

How do I find all string "ID" in an existed .txt file and get how many strings were found?

I have a .txt file like:

```
Product ID = "001", Product Name = "P1"

Product ID = "002", Product Name = "P2"

Product ID = "003", Product Name = "P3"

 ...
```

I would like to add `Product ID = "LASTEST_ID_PLUS_1, Product Name = "new"` at the end of file, but don't know how to get the last ID number.

Comment: Please share your code or your thoughts of how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The naive way would be read the file line by line and parse them for **Product ID = "** and store only the last id seen until you reach EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String filename = "test.txt";
int numOfIds = 0;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("Product ID = ")) {
            numOfIds++;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Should be a good starting point. Save up the last read ID and then use that for appending.

Edit:
After looking at your question again, I'm not even sure why your .txt file has `Product ID =`in it. Make the txt file look like this for much easier handling:

```
001,P1
002,P2
003,P3
```

unless you didn't show the entire file and there are different things than product IDs stored.

Comment: Beware that this solution assumes the product IDs are stored serially and without gaps - and if that is the actual case of the data, then reading the very last line, parsing out the ID, converting to int, and incrementing will also work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
 while(CurLine = in.readLine())

 //after exiting the loop
```

you can use StringBuilder methods "indexOf" and "subString".
then you can catch the last id.

Answer (score 1):

```
LineNumberReader lnr = null;
try {
    File file = new File("productList.txt");
    lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));
    lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    int lineNumber = lnr.getLineNumber();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));
    String productName = getProductName(); // may be a user input
    out.println("Product ID = \""+lineNumber+"\", Product Name = \""+productName+"\"\n");
    out.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle it
} finally {
    try {
        lnr.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(H.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I've assumed each line contains a product and sequence number start with 1.